# toggle show/hide div with button? load state hidden

Tags: jquery, html

I am using Jquery to toggle hide/show a div with:

HTML:

```
<div id="newpost">
    Test text
</div>

<button>Click</button>
```

Jquery:

```
$("button").click(function() {
    $("#newpost").toggle();
});
```

(the above is working perfectly)

from: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/KpFRb/

How can I change the state on page load to be hidden?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use style="display:none"

or hidden="true"

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="newpost" style="display:none">
    Test text
</div>
```

try this by adding this css to the div

Answer (score 1):

Add css or style to mark it `display:none`

See the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KpFRb/126/)